# Javascript not passing all the parameters

Tags: javascript

is that possible to call Javascript function without supply all the parameters?

I come across a line of code doesn't make much sense unless I assume that in Javascript supply all the parameters are not required?

The parameter been missed is a boolean value, so could I further assume that undefined boolean value in Javascript equal to 'false'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the other parameters will just be `undefined` if they're not passed in :)

For example:

```
function myFunc(param1, param2) {
  alert(param1);
  alert(param2);
}
```

This is a valid call:

```
myFunc("string"); //alerts "string" then undefined
```

[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/mu7AV/).  If the check in your question is something like `if(!param2)`, it'll evaluate to `true`, since `undefined ~= false` for most purposes.  It's worth noting this is not only acceptable, it's *very* common, almost every library or framework expects only *some* of the parameters to be passed into most of their functions.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Nick's response, you could have:

```
// set the value to false if not passed
if (typeof(param2) === "undefined") param2 = false;
```

Comment: Good addition, so missed parameter is not 'true' nor 'false'?

Comment: Nick points out that the value is undefined...which is not equal to false...this is just a way of explicitly checking to see if it is undefined and then setting it to a default (As per your suggested value)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [Variadic Functions](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/variadic_functions_in_javascript.aspx) in javascript. You can actually pass any type/number of parameters to any javascript function and use `arguments` to retrieve those parameters.

```
function PrintList()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
  {
    document.write(arguments[i] + "<br />");
  }
}
// Calls to Function
PrintList('Google');
PrintList('Google', 'Microsoft', 'Yahoo');
PrintList('Google', 'Microsoft', 'Yahoo', 'Adobe');
```